# CFNotificationCenterRemoveEveryObserver not removing the observer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using CFNotificationCenterAddObserver() function to register a notification as below

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                                NULL,
                                ringerSwitched,
                                CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.ringerstate"),
                                NULL,
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

Later at some point I am removing it via CFNotificationCenterRemoveEveryObserver() function as below but call back method is still getting called.

```
CFNotificationCenterRemoveEveryObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), NULL);
```

I also used CFNotificationCenterRemoveObserver() function to unregister but no use.

```
CFNotificationCenterRemoveObserver (CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), NULL, CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.ringerstate"), NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

providing an identifier for your observer.

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(),
                            "observer identifier",
                            ringerSwitched,
                            CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.ringerstate"),
                            NULL,
                            CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);

CFNotificationCenterRemoveEveryObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), @"observer identifier");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found the solution at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082100/cfnotificationcenterremoveobserver-observer). As you mentioned, it is not @"observer identifier" rather it could be a c string. i.e "observer identifier"