# Listen for power button event in OS X

Tags: c++, macos

When the power button is pressed I am presented with the following dialogue box, and this notification if dispatched:

`__CFNotification 0x10011f410 {name = com.apple.logoutInitiated; object = 501}`

[image]

**Question: How can I listen for and act upon this event from a C++ application?**

fyi:

I have managed to hack together an Objective C snippet which does this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserverForName: nil
         object: nil
         queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
         usingBlock: ^(NSNotification *notification) {

             //The event notification we are looking for:
             //__CFNotification 0x10011f410 {name = com.apple.logoutInitiated; object = 501}

             NSString *event = notification.name;
             BOOL res = [event isEqualToString:@"com.apple.logoutInitiated"];
             if (res)
             {
                 printf("POWER BUTTON PRESSED");
             }
             else
             {
                 printf("IGNORE");
             }
         }];

        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run];
    }

}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe the above code does not *intercept* but simply *listens* for the notification.  (Nuance being that "interception" allows you to hide the notification to other processes which might also be listening for it.)

Comment: Yes sorry no interception needed, just to listen and act upon such event.

Comment: Is your C++ code in a mac app or a command line utility?

Comment: @trojanfoe, I fail to see how that changes anything.

Comment: @QwertyBob It doesn't, but I'm just trying to understand the restrictions that might apply to a possible solution.

Comment: In this case it's a mac app.

Comment: Have you considered implementing the app using Objective-C++, which is as simple as renaming all `.m` files to `.mm`.  You can freely use C++ from these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple c++ SCCE would look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

void
myCallBack(CFNotificationCenterRef center,
           void *observer,
           CFStringRef name,
           const void *object,
           CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {
    std::cout << "Power Button Pressed" << std::endl;
}

int
main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CFNotificationCenterRef distCenter;
    CFStringRef evtName = CFSTR("com.apple.logoutInitiated");
    distCenter = CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter();
    if (NULL == distCenter)
        return 1;
    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(distCenter, NULL, &myCallBack, evtName, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
    CFRunLoopRun();
    return 0;
}
```

and would be compiled using `clang++ -framework CoreFoundation testfile.cpp`.

How you hook it into your own application is another matter entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want to access the underlying functionality that `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` wraps around.

Perhaps you should look at [CFNotificationCenterRef](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001438) and more specifically [`CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter).

These aren't C++ per se, they're C functions, but you can call them from C++.

Answer (score 0):

The `CoreFoundation` has a nice API written in C, therefore you can use the `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver` function and link your C++ program to the necessary framework. Example:

```
clang++ <your options> -framework CoreFoundation
```

See the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/Reference/reference.html). A quick search here revealed [an example of how to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968677/cfnotificationcenter-usage-examples).