# How to listen power button event in macOS?

Tags: c++, macos

I have MacBook Air Retina(TouchID) and I need to listen power button pressing. How I do that?

I have tried this solution [Listen for power button event in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19690034/6752050) but didn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

void
myCallBack(CFNotificationCenterRef center,
           void *observer,
           CFStringRef name,
           const void *object,
           CFDictionaryRef userInfo) {
    std::cout << "Power Button Pressed" << std::endl;
}

int
main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    CFNotificationCenterRef distCenter;
    CFStringRef evtName = CFSTR("com.apple.logoutInitiated");
    distCenter = CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter();
    if (NULL == distCenter)
        return 1;
    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(distCenter, NULL, &myCallBack, evtName, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
    CFRunLoopRun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you need the actual power button, or will something like the `NSWorkspaceWillPowerOffNotification` work?

Comment: I need to listen the button, not shutdown event

Comment: I think the power button on my Mac sends a `NSEventTypeSystemDefined` event with subtype `NSEventSubtypePowerOff`.

Answer (score 0):

That mentioned solution is obsolete. Try this event name:

```
CFStringRef evtName = CFSTR("com.apple.system.loginwindow.shutdownInitiated");
```

Comment: I give accesibility permission but nothing happened? Why

Comment: Try yet another "com.apple.loginwindow.shutdownInitiated". If it does not help, I don't have a clue.

Comment: Anyone figured this out? None of these seem to work.