# iOS - Passing Values from an Object to it's Containing Class

Tags: iphone, ios4, super

The setup:

I have an AppDelegate and declared on that is CustomUIViewController.h and in that controller I have RandomName.h declared **(as an object, not a subclass)** can I use [super methodName] or similar to trigger a method on CustomUIViewController from a method on RandomName.h?

Or do I have to pass it to the appDelegate and then from there to CustomUIViewController? (How I have been doing it)

Thanks

P.S. Coffee is good.

Comment: Exactly in the project I'm working on it's a class that plays image sequences for me. What I'm attempting to find is another way of passing a "I'm done animating" value from RandomName back to CustomUIView without having to run it through AppDelegate.

Comment: For anyone looking at this thread, the notification center will work as well for the purpose.

Comment: Link for explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/how-to-send-and-receive-message-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I think I've understood your question. Pardon me if I didn't **;-)***

`super` doesn't work that way. You can simply call,

```
[appDelegate.customViewController methodName];
```

The other way is to pass the reference of the **customViewController** to **RandomName** object, something like,

```
[[RandomName alloc] initWithParent:self];
```

You have to keep the reference of **self** in **initWithParent** method, lets say the variable name is **parent**, and call the method like this,

```
[parent methodName];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's cleaner then what I'm currently doing.