# how do i tell my uitableviewcontroller to reloadData in a asynch socket

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm using cocoaAsyncSocket when i click on a button in my tableViewController to fetch the dat
I want in the function didReadData to call reloadData of my tableView.
how should get the reference of my tableView ? 
please tell me, if i should use appDelegate, singletons or simply send it as a parameter. or if my design all together is wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider having your socket class send a `NSNotification` which the table view controller listens to.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i want.
If it helps anyone here's how to use it
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/how-to-send-and-receive-message-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c