# Basic table program in iOS - How can I tell my table to reload data from the application delegate?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiapplicationdelegate

I've got your standard table application built right now. Window has a UINavigationController as its rootViewController, and that UINavigationController was initialized with its rootViewController as my custom UITableController.

My applications table data changes over time. If I open my application up from a suspended state then my data is stale. How do I get applicationWillEnterForeground to update my data? I tried something awkward like

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    HabitsTable* vc = [[HabitsTable alloc] init];
    [vc initCoreData];
    UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]      initWithRootViewController:vc];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
        [[[[self window] rootViewController] navigationController] rootViewController]
}
```

But, no surprise, that doesn't work. I'm not sure how to get at my UITableController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can see a nice example of how to use the class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/how-to-send-and-receive-message-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c).

Comment: Man, that was helpful. Learning about NSNotificationCenter will probably cause me to refactor my whole application now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your close try:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)[[self window] rootViewController];
HabitsTable *tableView = (HabitsTable*)[navController topViewController];
```

Comment: Ah, topViewController. That is most likely what I was looking for. I think I'm going to use NSNotificationCenter instead, since that will likely lead to much less code duplication.