# Sending a notification when the operation has been completed in one class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsnotificationcenter

I have two classes, Class A and Class B.

Class A has a method

```
 -(void)methodA:(id)sender
{

}
```

and Class B has a method

```
-(void)methodB:(id)sender
{

}
```

Now i have some work is happening in methodA ,So once it is completed i want to send a notification from methodA: to methodB: So i can do some operation on the basis of notification.

So how can i do this? Can anybody guide me as i am new to obj-c?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send and receive message through NSNotificationCenter in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/how-to-send-and-receive-message-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use delegate. Simple code from wiki: visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

- A delegate is an object whose objects are (generally) called to handle or respond to specific events or actions.
- You must "tell" an object which accepts a delegate that you want to be the delegate. This is done by calling [object setDelegate:self]; or setting object.delegate = self; in your code.
- The object acting as the delegate should implement the specified delegate methods. The object often defines methods either in a protocol, or on NSObject via a category as default/empty methods, or both. (The formal protocol approach is probably cleaner, especially now that Objective-C 2.0 supports optional protocol methods.)
- When a relevant event occurs, the calling object checks to see if the delegate implements the matching method (using -respondsToSelector:) and calls that method if it does. The delegate then has control to do whatever it must to respond before returning control to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way.

In Class B's `-(id)initWithNibName: Bundle:` you will need to add in registering for NSNotifications.

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
      self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
      if (self) {

         // Custom initialization        
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                  selector:@selector(methodB:) 
                                                      name:@"methodAFinished" 
                                                    object:nil];

      }

      return self;

}
```

And then you need to do the following in the Class A methodA: function.

```
 - (void)methodA:(id)sender {

       // Once you have completed your actions do the following

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"methodAFinished" object:nil];

 }

 - (void)methodB:(id)sender {

      // This will then be called in the other class, do whatever is needed in here.

 }
```

Hope that works for you!

Also, don't forget, in Class B's `-(void)viewDidDisappear:animated` function, you need to unregister for the notifications.

```
 - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

       [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

 }
```

That should accomplish what you're asking for. Please add to your question if this isn't what you're working or comment below and I can rectify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Register an Observer in Class B like :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(method:) name:@"notificationName" object:nil];
```

And Post the notification from Class A like:

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationname" object:nil];
```

Remove the Observer in your class B, when it is deallocated like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
```