# Invoking a running CCLayer method from the AppController

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am currently programming a Cocos2d game for iOS.

In this game, I created a GameState singleton in order to save my game status (items details and positions, duration, score, etc.).

My main CCScene contains a `-(void) saveData:` method which, when invoked from within the running game (player hit the backToMenu button -> `-(void) backToMenu:`), performs accordingly:

We are sent back to the menu where, because `GameState.sharedState -> PLAYING = true`, a Resume button appear and allows us to resume the current game.

Until here, it works expectedly.

Now, how could I invoke the method `-(void) backToMenu:` from the `appController`'s method `applicationWillEnterBackground`?

I tried invoking the `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene]` but it crashes somehow, also on resume, which means I am not even sure I saved proper contents.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would take the NSNotification option. It's safer than a reference in the app delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Just found about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/how-to-send-and-receive-message-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c).
Could I, for example, create an `NSNotification` in the appController's `applicationWillEnterBackground` method, then handle it within my CCLayer object in which I'd add an NSObserver in its `init` method to receive such notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in AppDelegate.h :

```
@class CCLayer;

@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, CCDirectorDelegate,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
    CCLayer             *mCurrentLayer;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLayer *currentLayer;
```

Add this in AppDelegate.mm :

```
@implementation AppController
@synthesize currentLayer = mCurrentLayer;
```

In your Layer init class use this. In all scene method.

```
@implementation MyMainMenu

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    MyMainMenu *layer = [MyMainMenu node];

    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    app.currentLayer = layer;

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

You can check anywhere in project..

In appDelegate

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application 
{
   if([self.currentLayer  isKindOfClass:[MyMainMenu class]])
   MyMainMenu *mm = (MyMainMenu*) self.currentLayer;
   [mm calFunction]; 
}
```

In other class:

```
-(void)callUpdateButtonsInLayer
{    
     AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     if([app.currentLayer  isKindOfClass:[MyMainMenu class]])
     {
         MyMainMenu *mm = (MyMainMenu*) app.currentLayer;
         [mm calFunction]; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! What would be the most recommended option ? this one, or using an NSNotification/NSObserver (check my update above)?

Comment: in my game, I use one single instance class for game flow management, and with that class I do all these..Notification s last option. Don't go for notification if there exists possible path for data flow.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with your solution, then.