# Handling events in iOS

Tags: ios, events, notifications, sms

Does the iOS SDK support system services' event handling? I mean, could I have my app listening for external events such as sms reception, battery level of charge...

I was looking for documentation at iOS developers' site, and it looks like the only types of events I can handle are user events when interacting with the UI, events triggered by UI controls, Cocoa events, accelerometer and GPS events: [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW1)

Are those actually all the events that can be listened in an app, or am I missing some other documentation about system events as the ones I mentioned?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check out the NSNotificationCenter.  Check out this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/how-to-send-and-receive-message-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For battery level change look at [UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification defined in UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) - you can do:

```
// Register for battery level and state change notifications.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(batteryLevelDidChange:)
                                             name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Here's an apple sample:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BatteryStatus/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008812-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Not sure about SMS events - found mentions of it not being available via public APIs but that may have changed.  Not aware of anything.