# On receiving a notification i want to change my uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

The notification I receive contains an url to open in a `UIWebView`. But I cannot access the `UIWebview` from my `AppDelegate` (this is where is receive the `notification`).

```
-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification(NSDictionary* ) userInfo{
      // handle notification (this works)
      //HERE I want to call my UIWebView and load the url I got.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to post a notification that your `UIWebView` receives. Check out the [NSNotificationCenter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [this example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191802/184245).

Answer (score 1):

In my app I have used the following, this is when the `UIWebView` is already on the screen:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSString *urlString = [userInfo objectForKey:@"url"];
    if( [self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] ){
        UINavigationController *currentNavigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
        if( [currentNavigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[NHCallVC class]] ){
            SomeViewController *currentViewController = (SomeViewController*)currentNavigationController.visibleViewController;
            [currentViewController.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
        }
    }
}
```

The structure with the `UINavigationController` seems complex, but this was needed for the way I set up my app. This can be different in your app.

The idea is to get the viewcontroller that is opened and load a URL on the `UIWebView`. The code is assuming the `UIViewController` with the `UIWebView` is currently open. The code should be altered if you want to navigate to the correct `UIViewController` before opening the url in the `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

Place an observer to the view where UIWebView resides such as:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(recievedNotification:) name:@"ReceivedNotification" object:nil];
```

Write the appropriate code within recievedNotification function which changes the UIWebView's target url.

And post a notification in didReceiveRemoteNotification function in APP Delegate such as:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReceivedNotification" object:nil];
```

Good luck.