# Set address string with reverseGeocodeLocation: and return from method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, clgeocoder, completionhandler

I'm try to localize a start and end point to an address string, so that I can store it into `NSUserDefaults`. The problem is that the method continues executing and does not set my variable.

```
NSLog(@"Begin");

__block NSString *returnAddress = @"";

[self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locManager.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

    startAddressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                          placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                          placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                          placemark.administrativeArea,
                          placemark.country];
    returnAddress = startAddressString;

    //[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}];
NSLog(returnAddress);

NSLog(@"Einde");
```

This is what my application debugger shows:

> start
>   einde

If for example the address of my location is : "Mainstreet 32, CITY". Then what i would want to see is the following:

> Start
>   Mainstreet 32, CITY
>   Einde

The problem is that my code does not wait for my `CLGeocoder` to finish, so my variable `returnAddress` is not set when it is returned, and it is empty.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `reverseGeocodeLocation` has a completion block, it is handed off to another thread when execution reaches it - but execution on the main thread will still continue onto the next operation, which is `NSLog(returnAddress)`. At this point, `returnAddress` hasn't been set yet because `reverseGeocodeLocation` was JUST handed off to the other thread.

When working with completion blocks, you'll have to start thinking about working asynchronously.

Consider leaving `reverseGeocodeLocation` as the last operation in your method, and then calling a new method with the remainder of the logic inside the completion block. This will ensure that the logic doesn't execute until you have a value for `returnAddress`.

```
- (void)someMethodYouCall 
{
    NSLog(@"Begin");
    __block NSString *returnAddress = @"";

    [self.geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:self.locManager.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject];

        startAddressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                              placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                              placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                              placemark.administrativeArea,
                              placemark.country];
        returnAddress = startAddressString;

        //[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        NSLog(returnAddress);
        NSLog(@"Einde");

        // call a method to execute the rest of the logic 
        [self remainderOfMethodHereUsingReturnAddress:returnAddress];
    }];
// make sure you don't perform any operations after reverseGeocodeLocation.
// this will ensure that nothing else will be executed in this thread, and that the
// sequence of operations now follows through the completion block.
}

- (void)remainderOfMethodHereUsingReturnAddress:(NSString*)returnAddress {
   // do things with returnAddress.
}
```

Or you can use NSNotificationCenter to send a notification when `reverseGeocodeLocation` is complete. You can subscribe to these notifications anywhere else you need it, and complete the logic from there. Replace `[self remainderOfMethodHereWithReturnAddress:returnAddress];` with:

```
NSDictionary *infoToBeSentInNotification = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:returnAddress forKey:@"returnAddress"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:@"NameOfNotificationHere" 
    object:self
    userInfo: infoToBeSentInNotification];
    }];
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c) an example of using NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: Yes i know, but in my case I need to use that variable outside of the completion block. Because i have some other logic outside the block wich i cannot put inside the block. Do you know a way to do that? And do you have a link or sample for me of the asynchronously threading?. Thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer with some ways you could execute the remainder of your logic with the return address you need.

Comment: Awesome, i've figured it out now! Thanks.