# Swift - CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation completionHandler closure

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, cllocation

What I'm trying to do is pass a `CLLocation` to the function `getPlacemarkFromLocation` which then uses the passed `CLLocation` through `reverseGeocodeLocation` to set the `CLPlacemark?` that will be returned.

I'm having issues creating the `completionHandler` closure in `reverseGeocodeLocation`, <strike>it's throwing a compiler error/crash:</strike>

In Swift, `CLGeocodeCompletionHandler` is `CLGeocodeCompletionHandler = (AnyObject[]!, NSError!) -> Void` according to the documentation `AnyObject[]!` is supposed to contain `CLPlacemark` objects just like the Objective-C version.

Here's my current code:

```
class func getPlacemarkFromLocation(location:CLLocation)->CLPlacemark?{
    var g = CLGeocoder()
    var p:CLPlacemark?
    g.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks, error) in
        let pm = placemarks as? CLPlacemark[]
        if (pm && pm?.count > 0){
            p = placemarks[0] as? CLPlacemark
        }
    })
    return p?
}
```

EDIT: It seems like the error had to do with `placemarks.count` with `placemarks` not being treated like an array. It compiles now, however I'm getting nothing but nil when trying to set `p` inside the `completionHandler`. I've checked the `CLLocation`s being passed and they are valid.

EDIT 2: After printing `placemarks`, I can confirm that it returns data. However `p` is still returning nil.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the answer I needed in this thread: [Set address string with reverseGeocodeLocation: and return from method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346516/xcode-ios-clgeocoder-reversegeocodelocation-return-addressstring)

The issue lies with the fact that `reverseGeocodeLocation` is asynchronous, the method is returning a value before the completionBlock sets `p` in my example.

As requested, here's my current code.

```
func showAddViewController(placemark:CLPlacemark){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("add", sender: placemark) 
}

func getPlacemarkFromLocation(location: CLLocation){
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler:
        {(placemarks, error) in
            if error {println("reverse geodcode fail: \(error.localizedDescription)")}
            let pm = placemarks as [CLPlacemark]
            if pm.count > 0 { self.showAddPinViewController(placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark) }
    })
}
```

I didn't want to take the NSNotificationCenter route because that would add unnecessary overhead, rather inside the `completionHandler` closure I call upon another function and pass the `CLPlacemark` generated by `getPlacemarkFromLocation` as a parameter to keep things asynchronous since the function will be called after `placemarks` is set the function (should) receive the placemark needed and execute the code you want. Hope what I said makes sense.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you've solved your issue? I've tried external functions and notifications and still am receiving EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Thanks in advance, this would help other devs transitioning to Swift.

Comment: sorry, I was using this syntax...
`self!.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler:{ [weak self] (placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
// Your code here.
})

`

Comment: Sure, I'll edit this post and add my current code and elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 15):

With these lines of Swift, you can print out fully the location's address:

```
func getLocationAddress(location:CLLocation) {
    var geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    println("-> Finding user address...")

    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in
        var placemark:CLPlacemark!

        if error == nil && placemarks.count > 0 {
            placemark = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark

            var addressString : String = ""
            if placemark.ISOcountryCode == "TW" /*Address Format in Chinese*/ {
                if placemark.country != nil {
                    addressString = placemark.country
                }
                if placemark.subAdministrativeArea != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + placemark.subAdministrativeArea + ", "
                }
                if placemark.postalCode != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + placemark.postalCode + " "
                }
                if placemark.locality != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + placemark.locality
                }
                if placemark.thoroughfare != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + placemark.thoroughfare
                }
                if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + placemark.subThoroughfare
                }
            } else {
                if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {
                    addressString = placemark.subThoroughfare + " "
                }
                if placemark.thoroughfare != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + placemark.thoroughfare + ", "
                }
                if placemark.postalCode != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + placemark.postalCode + " "
                }
                if placemark.locality != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + placemark.locality + ", "
                }
                if placemark.administrativeArea != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + placemark.administrativeArea + " "
                }
                if placemark.country != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + placemark.country
                }
            }

            println(addressString)
        }
    })
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Here is closure that worked for me -- it took awhile to get it to work. I think your problem is related to not initializing p with the correct initializer. I tried a few variations until I got this to work: self.placemark = CLPlacemark(placemark: stuff[0] as CLPlacemark)

```
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(newLocation, completionHandler: {(stuff, error)->Void in

        if error {
            println("reverse geodcode fail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if stuff.count > 0 {
            self.placemark = CLPlacemark(placemark: stuff[0] as CLPlacemark)

            self.addressLabel.text = String(format:"%@ %@\n%@ %@ %@\n%@",
                self.placemark.subThoroughfare ? self.placemark.subThoroughfare : "" ,
                self.placemark.thoroughfare ? self.placemark.thoroughfare : "",
                self.placemark.locality ? self.placemark.locality : "",
                self.placemark.postalCode ? self.placemark.postalCode : "",
                self.placemark.administrativeArea ? self.placemark.administrativeArea : "",
                self.placemark.country ? self.placemark.country : "")
        }
        else {
            println("No Placemarks!")
            return
        }

        })
```

EDIT:

moved better answer to its own answer.

Comment: It does seem like `p` not being initialized is the issue, so I've changed `p = placemarks[0] as? CLPlacemark` to `p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks[0] as? CLPlacemark)` however p still returns nil. I tried initializing `p` before `reverseGeocodeLocation` is called, however I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to change the value. I cannot use the `CLPlacemark(placemark: CLPlacemark?)` initializer beforehand because I have no `CLPlacemark` to give

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This doesn't work. The value is nil outside the closure -- see comments below

Your p is nil because the closure is capturing it before it is initialized to a reference. To get the behavior you want you need to make p a non-optional value such as var p : CLPlacemark!.

Below is code I used to test my conjecture:

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
    var g = CLGeocoder()
    var p:CLPlacemark?
    let mynil = "empty"
    g.reverseGeocodeLocation(newLocation, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks, error) in
        let pm = placemarks as? CLPlacemark[]
        if (pm && pm?.count > 0){
           // p = CLPlacemark()
            p = CLPlacemark(placemark: pm?[0] as CLPlacemark)

            println("Inside what is in p: \(p?.country ? p?.country : mynil)")

        }

        })

    println("Outside what is in p: \(p?.country ? p?.country : mynil)")

}
```

Here is console log:

Pushit <- button pressed to start location capturing
Outside what is in p: empty
Inside what is in p: United States
Outside what is in p: empty
Inside what is in p: United States
Outside what is in p: empty...

Comment: I've tried that as well however I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when doing so.

Comment: I've tried it again, I'm getting the same result as your example above when using a non-optional value.

Comment: Closures for swift don't appear to work as I would expect. The only way I could get the inside value to "stick" outside the closure is if the placemark was a member variable of the controller. It would probably work with static/class variables if swift supported them (apparently not available in the beta).

Note, I even tried to use a local array initialized outside of the closure. I added (appended) the placemark to the array in the closure. But outside the closure the array was still employ.

Comment: Aaron, your solution below makes perfect sense. Good job. It was fun fooling with this I learned a lot about Swift closures. I would comment in the relevant answer if I was enabled to... :)

Comment: As of Beta 3, Array types are now written with the brackets around the element type...

Change:
`let pm = placemarks as? CLPlacemark[]`
to:
`let pm = placemarks as? [CLPlacemark]`

Comment: Yep. Noticed that yesterday. Quite strange. I'll make an edit

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to this party, but it looks like you need(ed) to do some ground-up reading about async stuff. Saying that, you've probably learnt it by now.

The basic problem with your code is that p (your placemark) is being set after the function returns, so it's just lost - you can't use a function to return a value with async. With a completion closure, your code is passed the placemark when it arrives (asynchronously) & the closure is invoked - note the function is now returning nothing.

```
func getPlacemarkFromLocation(_ location: CLLocation, completion: ((CLPlacemark?) -> ())) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        // use optional chaining to safely return a value or nil
        // also using .first rather than checking the count & getting placemarks[0] -
        // if the count is zero, will just give you nil
        // probably a good idea to check for errors too
        completion(placemarks?.first)
    })
}
```

Use -

```
getPlacemarkFromLocation(myLocation, completion: { (placemark) in
    // do something with the placemark here
})
```

I've not actually put this into Xcode, but it looks right...

Answer (score -4):

Your stuff doesn't work for a number of reasons.  Here's the part that I fixed without actually looking at the functionality:

```
class func getPlacemarkFromLocation(location:CLLocation)->CLPlacemark?{
    var g = CLGeocoder()
    var p:CLPlacemark?
    g.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks, error) in
        let pm = placemarks!
        if (pm.count > 0){
            p = placemarks![0]
        }
    })
    return p
}
```

Comment: This will still return nil - you're not realising that p is set after you return the value, as reverseGeocodeLocation works async