# What's the best way to get an address from an annotation?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to have a user click an annotation and in the next view some information such as an address is represented in a `UITextField`. However when trying to get `annotation.subtitle` I get an error regarding the return value of MKAnnotation.subtitle to be String?? instead of what I want, String. Should I be using `reverseGeocodeLocation` ?

Comment: yes, MapKit provide this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - CLGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation completionHandler closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345296/swift-clgeocoder-reversegeocodelocation-completionhandler-closure)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use it you will get a `CLPlacemark` Object, that contain, name, address...

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)CLPlacemark

Comment: do you have example code for what it looks like, I'm having trouble getting reverseGeocoding working. Especially because it's in a function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345296/swift-clgeocoder-reversegeocodelocation-completionhandler-closure