# How to get place name from lattitude and longitude?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-geocoder

I am getting the latitude and longitude from the api, and need to get the place name from these cooridinates so that I use this block of code

```
CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

CLLocation *LocationAtual=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[latlong objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue] 
                                                     longitude:[[latlong objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]];

NSLog(@"loc %@", LocationAtual);

[ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:LocationAtual  completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
{
  CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
  NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
  //String to hold address
  NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
  NSLog(@"addressDictionary %@", placemark.addressDictionary);

  NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.region);
  NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.country);  // Give Country Name
  NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.locality); // Extract the city name
  NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.name);
  NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.ocean);
  NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.postalCode);
  NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.subLocality);

  NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.location);

  NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);
  NSLog(@"  ");
}
];
```

But when my control goes on this line

```
 [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:LocationAtual  completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
```

this block of code is not executed. Control goes.

Comment: Yes sir i have issue with this concept

Comment: yes sir i will read about it, but can you help me for now

Comment: Get it from here @sandeep http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346516/set-address-string-with-reversegeocodelocation-and-return-from-method

Comment: @sandeeptomar Please print your LocationAtual value.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh these are the values sir 28.566540 77.209841 error i get these values from api

Comment: ok to be to the point tell me :
NSLog(@"loc %@", LocationAtual); what it prints ?
NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark); what this prints ?
NSLog(@"addressDictionary %@", placemark.addressDictionary); what this prints ?

Comment: sir i am checking step by step using breakpoints

Comment: placemark CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+28.56713205,+77.21233975> radius 471.64', center:<+28.56713205,+77.21233975>, radius:471.64m)
2 placemark India
 placemark New Delhi
 location All India Institute Of Medical Sciences - AIIMS
 location (null)
 location 110029
location Ansari Nagar
location <+28.56713200,+77.21182200> +/- 100.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 25/05/2016 13:11:55 India Standard Time
2016-05-25 13:11:55.759 GGR Driver Staging[13889:8711845] I am currently at All India Institute Of Medical Sciences - AIIMS, Ansari Nagar, New Delhi, Delhi 110029, India

Comment: City = "New Delhi";
    Country = India;
    CountryCode = IN;
    FormattedAddressLines =     (
        "All India Institute Of Medical Sciences - AIIMS",
        "Ansari Nagar",
        "New Delhi",
        "Delhi 110029",
        India
    );
    Name = "All India Institute Of Medical Sciences - AIIMS";
    State = Delhi;
    SubAdministrativeArea = Delhi;
    SubLocality = "Ansari Nagar";
    ZIP = 110029;

Comment: @Alok But sir when i tried to add breakpoints in block its not working

Comment: that's what @trojanfoe is telling you . This process is call Asynchronous (don't ever say control goes :) ). Your code is working perfectly.  Now you can use Notification Center to be notified that your callback method have got some values you are interested in.

Comment: ok sir thanks for clear my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` OfYour class or any other class just add:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Add observer
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gotPlaceInfo:) name:@"gotPlaceInfoNotification" object:nil];
}

//define `gotPlaceInfo`:
-(void)gotPlaceInfo:(NSNotification *)notif{

NSLog(@"place mark dict is  %@", notif.userInfo);
}
```

i have just add a single line in your code:

```
    CLGeocoder *ceo = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

    CLLocation *LocationAtual=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[latlong objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue] 
                                                         longitude:[[latlong objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue]];

    NSLog(@"loc %@", LocationAtual);

    [ceo reverseGeocodeLocation:LocationAtual  completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
    {
      CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

NSDictionary *currentLocationDictionary = @{@"CLPlacemark":CLPlacemark};
      NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark);
      //String to hold address
      NSString *locatedAt = [[placemark.addressDictionary valueForKey:@"FormattedAddressLines"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
      NSLog(@"addressDictionary %@", placemark.addressDictionary);

      NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.region);
      NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.country);  // Give Country Name
      NSLog(@"placemark %@",placemark.locality); // Extract the city name
      NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.name);
      NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.ocean);
      NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.postalCode);
      NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.subLocality);

      NSLog(@"location %@",placemark.location);

      NSLog(@"I am currently at %@",locatedAt);
      NSLog(@"  ");
NSNotification *notification2 = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"gotPlaceInfoNotification" object:self userInfo:currentLocationDictionary];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification2];
    }
    ];
```

Hope it will give you a overall learning

Comment: Yes sir this is work for me and thanks for understand me a new concept for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code from Ram G answer of [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515639/iphone-get-city-name-from-latitude-and-longtiude) it works for you

```
- (void) getAddressFromLatLon:(CLLocation *)bestLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%f %f", bestLocation.coordinate.latitude, bestLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init] ;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:bestLocation
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
            return;
        }
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"placemark.ISOcountryCode %@",placemark.ISOcountryCode);
        NSLog(@"locality %@",placemark.locality);
        NSLog(@"postalCode %@",placemark.postalCode);

    }];

}
```

Comment: get the same problem sir

Comment: this block not executed  [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:bestLocation
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error){
             NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
             return;
         }
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
         NSLog(@"placemark.ISOcountryCode %@",placemark.ISOcountryCode);
         NSLog(@"locality %@",placemark.locality);
         NSLog(@"postalCode %@",placemark.postalCode);
         
     }];

Comment: CLLocationManagerDelegate declare it in .h file and import  #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

Comment: import this one #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

Comment: Are you getting proper lat long?

Comment: @VidhiPatel yeah coordinates are fine. should i use didupdatelocation method

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap any reason why his code not working ? how your code differ from OP

Comment: Remove return from this code if (error){ NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);return;} and check this error is print or not