# iOS correctly resume after application becomes active

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm building a game for iOS using Cocos2D. In my game I have a pause menu that can be pulled up when playing the game. A simple tap will return from the pause menu to the game. What I would like to implement is a clean way to resume the game on the pause menu if the method `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called. The problem is that only the appDelegate receives the call to `applicationDidBecomeActive`, and my pause menu is many layers deeper than that. Right now I'm essentially passing the `applicationDidBecomeActive` call through about 4 different layers to get it down to the pause menu. There must be a cleaner way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure is. Just add an observer for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` from anywhere that's convenient. Application state changes can be hooked that way as well as via the app's delegate.

([Docs here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Answer (score 1):

Read about the NSNotificationCenter 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c) and [at Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or just receive the [UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

take a BOOL variable in appdelegate.h with property and synthesised it then when pause button pressed from any scene set this variable to yes.
in applicationDidBecomeActive method of appdelegate check if(self.pause == YES) then don't resume ccdirector else resume it
i used this in my game and it work fine when i press pause and then press home button and when come back the app is still pause. try this