# How to call Notification from another class

Tags: iphone, ios

I try to call Notification for another class

// Which is in ClassA

```
- (void)onDidFinishLaunchingNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLOG(@"onDidFinishLaunchingNotification");
}
```

calling notification from another class
// Which is in Class B

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:nil selector:@selector(onDidFinishLaunchingNotification:) name:nil object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Class A, add self as an observer of the notification with a name

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(onDidFinishLaunchingNotification:)
                                             name:YourOnDidFinishLaunchingNotificationName
                                           object:nil];
```

and in Class B, use `-postNotificationName:object:` to post the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:YourOnDidFinishLaunchingNotificationName
                                                    object:nil];
```

Comment: when i am calling [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:YourOnDidFinishLaunchingNotificationName
                                                    object:nil]; my application is crashing!

Comment: @kiran make sure the `selector` is the same to the message name: `onDidFinishLaunchingNotification:`, don't forget the COLON.

Answer (score 1):

in Class B you shuold addObserver to B like this :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(onDidFinishLaunchingNotification:)
                                             name:YourOnDidFinishLaunchingNotificationName
                                           object:nil];
```

I think you should to look at the document of the [addObserver:selector:name:object:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object:)

and here is a very [useful example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c/2191802#2191802) for using `NSNotification`