# iOS: Activity Indicator and WebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a scenario when the document takes time to download in a webview , user can press a cancel button provided in the activity indicator and can stop the downloading. I am using a different library for activity indicator. I need to know in webview that the button has been clicked in activity indicator or how can I have access to webview in activity indicator library. Can I set the activity indicator cancel button selector method in some other file? Quick help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `Delegation` or `Notification` to tell the Class that contains UIWebView that cancel button has been pressed in another class(your Activity Indicator class).

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotificationCenter for get the Cancel button pressed event:

**Add Observer**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(cancelButtonClicked:) name:@"cancelButton" object:nil];
```

**Implement Cancel method**

```
-(void)cancelButtonClicked:(NSNotification *)notification{
   // Do your action here
}
```

And also don't forget to remove observer once done with cancel:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

For detail check this one :

[Send and receive messages through NSNotificationCenter in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c)