# How to communicate between a UISplitView Master and Detail without importing each other's headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to determine what is the best practice for sending data from a UISplitViews Master to it's Detail. I want to try to avoid importing headers and make the code as reusable as possible. I feel like there should be a really good way of doing this, but the best I can think of is to declare a protocol, but sometimes protocols can get a bit messy IMHO. and talking to the detail by using

```
[self setDelegate:id<myProtocol>)self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Seems kind of flaky

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to import each other headers and dont want to use a delegate, the only thing I can think of is using Notifications:

[Send and receive messages through NSNotificationCenter in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c)

You can pass information in a dictionary to the notification

Comment: That actually seems interesting. I like this idea.

Comment: I experimented with this and decided that I really like it. TYVM

Answer (score 0):

You could just go ahead and use your appDelegate to hold different variables and access them from your viewcontrollers. But I would recommend creating a new Singleton class which will do that for you.

For example, create a class called e.g. `Holder.h` + `.m` and declare all the needed variables.

.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *someArray;
```

.m

```
+(id)sharedHolder{
static Holder *holder = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    holder = [[self alloc] init];
});
return holder;
```

}

now you can set your variable by doing `[[Holder sharedHolder] setSomeArray:anotherArray]` and then read it from somewhere else like this: `[[Holder sharedHolder] someArray]`

EDIT:
You could also use Antonio's approach with `NSNotification`

Comment: That would work, but I tend avoid singletons as they are just globals in disguise