# Determining the UIViewController from which the current UIViewController was loaded

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7, uistoryboard

I have a main `UIViewController` which has an embedded Navigation Controller. I have 2 additional `UIViewController`s that are launched from the main `UIViewController` via push segues. When the user navigates from one of these two view controllers to the main UIViewController, I would like to identify from which `UIViewController` the user navigated from. How can I get this information?

Comment: Maybe if you let us know what your overall goal is we can provide a better solution. It's most likely that youre trying to have a dynamic viewcontroller based on the viewController that pushed it. If that is the case then simply pass a variable to that pushed viewcontroller and have that be the determining factor for the viewsetup instead of trying to figure who the parent ViewController is since that can always change in navigation changes :)

Comment: I need to do some actions in my main `UIViewController` when the user returns to it from one of the `UIViewController`s that were pushed.

Comment: Gotcha. So you have two parent view controllers that call the same viewcontroller lets call it VCB, and wen you do something on VCB it should send an action to the appropriate parentViewController that originally pushed VCB?

Comment: Have you tried `UINavigationControllerDelegate`? Set navigation controller delegate to you main `UIViewController`. It may be help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

1- Use delegation on the two `subviewControllers`, and use the main as the `delegate` handler.

2- Use `viewWillDisappear` on the two `subviewControllers`, and change a value on the main view controller by something like `self.presentedController.yourValue`

Hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You can jerry rig this but the 'right' way to do this in objective-c land is to use either a delegate or NSNotificationCenter. In this particular case I think NSNotificationCenter is probably easiest... there is a great example here: [Send and receive messages through NSNotificationCenter in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c)