# Segue Is Not Performed Visually

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm dealing with a segue problem and it's getting ridiculous.

I'm performing it like how I always do in a view controller named `LoginViewController` :

```
- (void)loginSuccessfullyAccomplished
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"switchToHome" sender:self];
}
```

The method above is called from another Class, where some other signing in actions is performed asynchronously, and when it is done, it calls this method from `LoginViewController.m` :

```
// Some Code
.
.
.
.
case VIDYO_CLIENT_OUT_EVENT_SIGNED_IN:
{
    /*** Notifying upper layer ( Login View Controller ) from signing in ***/
    UIStoryboard *storyboard;
    if ( IDIOM == IPAD )
    {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MasterStoryboard-iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    else if ( IDIOM == IPHONE )
    {
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MasterStoryboard-iPhone" bundle:nil];
    }
    UINavigationController *nav = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController] ;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [nav.viewControllers[0] loginSuccessfullyAccomplished];
    });
    break;
}
.
.
.
.
//Rest of the code
```

Now, Here's the problem :

`loginSuccessfullyAccomplished` is being called successfully (Used breakpoints to make sure of that), But I don't see the second view controller to appear on the screen.

I get no error and no exceptions when `performSegue` is executed, that means I'm not making any mistake regarding the segue identifier or first view controller from which the segue is being performed.

I'm also sure that I'm using a push segue and I HAVE embedded my view controllers in a navigation controller.

Just to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong with the segue itself, I implemented `prepareForSegue` method and it IS BEING called. I also have checked that it is pointing to correct destination :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ( [segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UserHomeViewController class]] )
    {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    }
}
```

The second view controller IS NOT visually similar to first view controller, so I definitely will notice if it changes.

I have no idea what is going wrong. Any suggestions is really appreciated.

Thanks.

P.S: I know there're dozens of " `performSegueWithIdentifier` not being called " questions but none of them helped my case!!!

Comment: On a second thought, I think I'm kinda making a mistake in choosing the instance of `LoginViewController` on which I'm calling the method !

Comment: Why are you initing a new storyboard?

Comment: Yep.  That's it @Unkn0wn.Bit.  I'd go with announcing to the world via NSNotificationCenter.  Here is a highly up voted example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is being called successfully, but on which instance?  The code in the `IDIOM == IPHONE` block is highly suspect.  It's calling `loginSuccessfullyAccomplished` on an brand new instance, one that hasn't been presented, so it's not a surprise that we wouldn't see any change in the UI.

What I think you need in the object where the login logic is running is a reference to the instance of the `LoginViewController` that's actually been presented.  You can do that by making it a delegate.  Maybe better, don't bother with pointers.... have the login logic post an `NSNotification` that login has finished, and have the `LoginViewController` observe that and dismiss itself.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out just a second before I see your post :D
Thanks