# Make UIButton disappear from UIViewController once a button in UIView is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController (JDTHViewController) with a UIView (JDTHMainMenu) In the  view controller are two buttons that each, once clicked, move to two other separate view controllers. In the UIView are two other buttons (options and stats) that, once clicked, create subviews on top of the view, minus a few pixels from each side, and therefore hide the two buttons so you can interact with the subviews. Now when I run the simulator all my buttons are in the right positions but once one of the UIViews buttons are clicked they disappear and the segue buttons (ViewController switch buttons) are on top of my subviews. I need these to disappear once 'options' or 'stats' is clicked. Is there a way to do this? I hope that made sense if not i'll post more info or code. Thanks!

Comment: `buttonName.hidden = YES;`

Comment: right but one buttons code is in the ViewController and the other is in the UIView, how would I reference a button made in the ViewController in the UIView to hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a delegate callback from the UIView to the viewController and hide it. If you want to hide two buttons at the same time sending a notification would be easier.

Comment: and yes it is two buttons

Answer (score 0):

`yourButton.hidden=1;` or `[yourButton setHidden:1];`
Instead of `1` you can use `YES`.
Do you mean this?

Comment: For ObjectiveC `BOOL` type argument you should pass `YES` or `NO`. Avoid passing `int` values.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean

```
buttonName.hidden = YES;
```

As you are in another class, hide it using [NSNotificationCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191802/1066828)

[Here is good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191802/1066828)

Comment: I think you and Nicael are right, but its where to put it when referencing a viewcontroller from a uiview

Comment: @JonHerbert : hmm, use [NSNotificationCenter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2191802/1066828)

Comment: I'm reading through it and trying to understand it, to see how i'll apply it to my situation

Comment: @JonHerbert : wokay... If you have any difficulty let me know... the link I gave is the easiest example ever I have...