# Animate colour changes of background to different View Controllers at same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have 3 different `ViewControllers` that are inside a combination of methods to get one result. During the process I need to change smoothly with some kind of animation the background colour dynamically to show possible different user behaviours. The question is:

Is there any way to change all backgrounds at same time or will I need to check what colour I have each time in each one and pass it to the next view controller and continue the animation there?

Comment: The solution I used to this was to pass from one controller to another a var with the parameters of the current state of the transition so i could continue the process from the same point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking if you can change the background on view controllers that are not yet loaded or on view - you can. However you need to pass the info to the view controller when you're about to display it on screen to the user. Then change colours in `viewWillAppear` or `ViewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

If your viewcontrollers are loaded. You can use `NSNotification`.
look this link
[Send and receive messages through NSNotificationCenter in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c)

Wherever you want to change color write the `receiveNotification` code in `viewDidLoad` and call a method with it.

May be it will work for you.