# iOS NSNotificationCenter to check whether the app came from background to foreground

Tags: ios, background, nsnotificationcenter, foreground

I have a situation in which i have to intialize an object everytime when it comes from background to foreground and that should be using the NSNotificationCenter not with appdelegate because iam building a static library so there wont be appdelegate with that so please help me in the same.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Have you tried `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`?

The app also posts a UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification notification shortly before calling `applicationWillEnterForeground:` to give interested objects a chance to respond to the transition.

Subscribe to notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(yourUpdateMethodGoesHere:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Implement a code, that need to be called:

```
- (void) yourUpdateMethodGoesHere:(NSNotification *) note {
// code
}
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c

Answer (score 29):

#### Swift 4.2

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification
            , object: nil)
```

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 5**

Subscribe to Notification -

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self,
      selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)),
      name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
      object: nil)
}
```

Remove subscription -

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Function to be called -

```
@objc func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ notification: NSNotification) {
       self.volumeSlider.value = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3 version**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector:#selector(applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)),
                                           name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground,
                                           object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ notification: NSNotification) {
   ....
}
```

you can also use `NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5 use:
UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification

Answer (score 3):

swift 5

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification.rawValue), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func appMovedToForeground() {
       // Do stuff
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3 and 4 version**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
        ...
}
```