# Detect when a view controller goes to background and gets resumed

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm implementing a ViewController with the following requirement: If the user returns to the app after 15 minutes, the view should reload the data.

I was thinking on using `viewDidDisappear` to save the timestamp when the app went to background and `viewDidAppear` for checking previously saved values and refresh if needed, but this methods are not getting called when switching between apps.

How can I solve this in a easy way?

Comment: I'm working with swift ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` for resume and `UIApplicationWillResignActive` for handle goes background

**SwiftUI**

```
Text("check application state!")
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification)) { _ in
                    print("User received on  willResignActiveNotification!")
                }
                .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
                    print("User received on  didBecomeActiveNotification!")
                }
```

**Swift 5.x > above**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name:  UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.openAndCloseActivity), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.openAndCloseActivity), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func openAndCloseActivity(_ notification: Notification)  {
    if notification.name == UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification{
        // become active notifictaion
    }else{
        // willResignActiveNotification
    }
    
}
```

**Swift 5.x < below**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.closeActivityController), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.openactivity), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)
   
    
}
```

and handle the method as

```
func closeActivityController()  {
    
    
}

func openactivity()  {
    
    //view should reload the data.
}
```

other notification types are

```
extension NSNotification.Name { 
@available(iOS 4.0, *)
public static let UIApplicationDidEnterBackground: NSNotification.Name

@available(iOS 4.0, *)
public static let UIApplicationWillEnterForeground: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationDidFinishLaunching: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationDidBecomeActive: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationWillResignActive: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning: NSNotification.Name

public static let UIApplicationWillTerminate: NSNotification.Name

}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910765/ios-nsnotificationcenter-to-check-whether-the-app-came-from-background-to-foregr

Comment: @LorenzoB - are you seen my answer i used the name `UIApplicationWillEnterForeground`  or `UIApplicationWillResignActive`

Comment: @LorenzoB - i am not copied the answer , if you think its dupliacte question you can mark as duplicate but answer is not duplicate

Comment: I do not think is copied. Just to highlight that OP question is really similar to the one I linked.

Comment: @LorenzoB - sorry my bro, i think u said my answer is duplicate

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anbu, will try it right now, but, if you unregister on viewWillDisappear then you should register in the viewWillAppear right?

Comment: @Adrime - absolutely corret, if you are in the same VC, then no need, else you need to move code from viewdidload to viewwillappear, thats all bro

Comment: These notification names are outdated in iOS 15.0.

Comment: @CableW - thankyou for valuable message, answer has been updated.

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 5**

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

Methods :

```
@objc func appMovedToBackground() {
       print("App moved to background!")
    }
@objc func appBecomeActive() {
       print("App become active")
    }
```

To remove observers

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
      let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name:UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If interested here is a RxSwift version

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification).subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
            
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)

NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification).subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in

}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(appMovedToBackground:)
       name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
     object:nil];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
   selector:@selector(appBecomeActive:)
       name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
     object:nil];
}

- (void)appMovedToBackground:(NSNotification *) notification  {
    NSLog(@"App Moved To Background");
}

- (void)appBecomeActive:(NSNotification *) notification {
    NSLog(@"App become active");
}
```

Don't forget to clear notifications when view gets disappear

Answer (score 0):

`UIApplicationDelegate` has these two functions:

```
applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)
applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)
```

These could well be what you need.