# How to implement an appdelegate in cocoa touch framework?

Tags: swift3

How to implement an appdelegate in own framework class?.Because i have to detect when app is entering to foreground/background. 
Ex: like, in android Applifecycle run in service class

Comment: There a equivalent notifications for that which you can listen to.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910765/ios-nsnotificationcenter-to-check-whether-the-app-came-from-background-to-foregr

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own App Delegate class by simply implementing the UIApplicationDelegate protocol:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class CustomAppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {}
```

Note you will have to implement the various app delegate methods in this class.

EDIT:

In order to call this from another class you can cast the appDelegate singleton as follows:

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? CustomAppDelegate {}
```

Comment: how to call this class from one Nsobject class?

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'FrameworkTest.AppDelegate'  to 'WalinnsTracker.TrackerDelegate'  . "FrameworkTest " tis is app delegate, " "WalinnsTracker " inside of framework