# Open settings from my app then handle comeback event

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, ios-lifecycle

I am opening setting from my application viewcontroller like this

```
if let url = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) as URL? {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

And after turning notifications on for my app, when I tap on back button on status bar (I repeat status bar that is on top with sim and battery information) to comeback to my app. Now I want to know that how my app will know that user is back.
`willappear` and `didappear` is not called.

Comment: Your app will receive `willEnterForeground` App delegate call and notification

Comment: Your `AppDelegate` will tell you when you are leaving/coming to your application.

Comment: so I cannot handle it in my view controller?

Comment: Fire notification from `AppDelegate` and listen in your `ViewController`.

Comment: Your view controller can subscribe to the relevant notification; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910765/ios-nsnotificationcenter-to-check-whether-the-app-came-from-background-to-foregr

Answer (score 1):

Your app delegate methods are colled that time:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication)
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
```