# Start function from popover view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have main viewcontroller that opens via popover segue other view controller with buttons.
On button click what I wish to happen is function from first viewcontroller fire and the popover will close. How do I do so properly?

[image]

On settings button click the popover open. Then when user click Manual Content Update the the view will close and start function on Projects Main viewController.

Comment: You can use unwind segues to do that.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: One solution is to use `NSNotificationCenter` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter`.

In your main UIViewController add:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(receivePopoverNotification:) 
        name:@"PopoverNotification"
        object:nil];
}

-(void) dealloc{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];    
}

- (void) receivePopoverNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated: YES];
    self.popover = nil;
}
```

In your `UIPopoverController` add:

```
-(IBAction) pressButton: (id) sender {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"PopoverNotification" 
        object:nil];
}
```