# How to navigate to a ViewController from NSObject Class in iOS?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am facing a problem from last week. My requirement is, I have to create a custom `NSObject` class in which I have to write all navigation method for all button Click action. And when I click a button, the button action will retrieve navigate method from that custom `NSObject` class according to click & navigate. But it's Not working. What I am implementing, I share my code below:

This is my `Method_Action_class.h` Class

```
   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   @interface Method_Action_class : NSObject
   -(void)login_method_called;
   @end
```

This is my `Method_Action_class.m` Class

```
   #import "Method_Action_class.h"
   #import "Home_ViewController.h"

   @implementation Method_Action_class

   -(void)login_method_called
   {
       UIWindow *window=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
       Home_ViewController *home = [[Home_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home_ViewController" bundle:nil];
       [window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:home animated:YES];

   }
   @end
```

When I call this method on Button click:

```
   #import "Method_Action_class.h"

   Method_Action_class *demo = [[Method_Action_class alloc] init];
   [demo login_method_called];
```

Note: `Method_Action_class` is my `NSObject` type class

Here code is running successfully without warning/Error, but not navigate to another class.

Please help me.

Comment: Hey Dude, I am also facing this type of problem. But i find out the solution. I'll share my code please check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your button click action You have to send your `UINavigationController` & current `ViewController`. Because `NSObject` class not found that controller.

In your Button Action put this Code:

```
[demo login_method_called:self.navigationController withCurrentViewController:self];
```

In your NSObject  .h class put this code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Home_ViewController.h"

@interface Method_Action_class : NSObject

- (void)login_method_called:(UINavigationController*)navigation  withCurrentViewController:(UIViewController*) controller;
@end
```

In your NSObject  .m class put this code:

```
#import "Method_Action_class.h"

@implementation Method_Action_class

-(void)login_method_called:(UINavigationController*)navigation  withCurrentViewController:(UIViewController*) controller
{
   Home_ViewController *home = [[Home_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home_ViewController" bundle:nil];
   [navigation pushViewController:home animated:YES];
}
@end
```

And Build your code, It's navigate successfully. :)

Answer (score 2):

Please use NSNotificationCenter and use PushView from that controller.Or u can use Custom Delegate.For this u can refer

[[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c)

Comment: Ok i'll try it and get back to u.