# How to pass data from one ViewController to MainViewController without using segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I want to send data from ParcelResultViewController to ViewController(Main) but I don't have connection segue between ParcelResultViewController and viewcontroller. I shared my storyboard image and code block.

How can handle this situation ?

**ParcelResultViewController.m**

```
if (nil == self.viewcontroller) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.viewcontroller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        self.viewcontroller.fieldAliases = self.gonderilenFeatureSet.fieldAliases;
        self.viewcontroller.displayFieldName = self.gonderilenFeatureSet.displayFieldName;

        NSLog(@"%@",[self.gonderilenFeatureSet.features objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    }

    //the details view controller needs to know about the selected feature to get its value
    self.viewcontroller.feature = [self.gonderilenFeatureSet.features objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

[image]

Comment: Since both controllers have access to that navigation controller, you can subclass it and set it's delegate to query example view controller. Then you can send messages to query example view controller through it's protocol methods.

Comment: `NSNotificationCenter`? Please see this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c) for more information on notification center.

Comment: @ozgur thank you for comments. Is this possible to use your recommendation for my issue ? ( Teşekkürler , gönderdiğiniz class işime yarar mı ? )

Comment: Definitely it is, but I would go with @Desdenova's suggestion and subclass the navigation controller which is reachable from both end, because using notification center too much makes it harder for you to keep track of what is sent to where.

Comment: @Desdenova How do I do this ? I have no idea :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send a notification from the parse controller with the data as object.

Use the `NSNotificationCenter` to do that.

Comment: I will try use `NSNotificationCenter` in project Thanks

Comment: @DavidAnsermot I tried but it didn't work.Can you help me ?  I created new simple example project this storyboard [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/h79cO.png) and this my code [link](https://gist.github.com/fozoglu/41b52b87503e19ad536e)

Comment: You sure to have connected outlet ? Because your code is right excepted the part of storyboard. I would not made this like this but used appdelegate, uiwindow etc. But its not the point. The code should work.

Comment: But I don't see where you add the view controller to the window

Comment: My view controller is at the top of screen , I added image of simple example. My data is coming null when trying to send value via clicking button.

Comment: @DavidAnsermot Finally I can . I was able to pass values. Thanks. I accept the answer.