# How to emit and receive signals in Objective-c like QT with signals and slots?

Tags: objective-c, qt, callback

In QT you can emit signals and use slots to act upon them.  Otherwise I have write lots of threads to wait for signals through global variables to act on.  QT's signals and slots seem to be much more efficient.

How to emit and receive signals in Objective-c like QT with signals and slots?  thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done via [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/) to broadcast [NSNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/) objects to other objects. For a simple example see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c).