# Set UILabel from another view controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control in a SettingsController.

The segmented control can display temperature in Celsius 
or Fahrenheit.

I have a mainViewController where I have the temperature label which displays current temperature in celsius.

On click of the segmented control I want to convert the temperature to appropriate unit and display it in the mainViewController.

```
@IBOutlet weak var temperatureUnitSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
var mainViewController : MainViewController?

@IBAction func temperatureSegmentedControlListener(sender: UISegmentedControl) {

        switch temperatureUnitSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        {
        case 0:
            showTemperatureInCelsius()
        case 1:
            showTemperatureInFahrenheit()
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    func showTemperatureInCelsius(){
        mainViewController?.setTempInCelsius()

    }
    func showTemperatureInFahrenheit(){
            mainViewController?.setTempInFahrenheit()
    }
```

In mainViewController I want to do the conversions and update the temperature label

```
func setTempInCelsius(){
        temperatureLabel.text = "In Celsius"
        log?.debug("Temperature Celsius\(batteryTemperatureLabel.text)")
    }

    func setTempInFahrenheit(){
        temperatureLabel.text = "In Fahrenheit"
        log?.debug("Temperature Fahrenheit\(batteryTemperatureLabel.text)")
    }
```

This code does not hit the functions in the mainViewController and value of the label does not get updated.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: For starters: Where do you set the variable `mainViewController`? Also, I assume the first code block you show is in that `SettingsController`? My guess would be that you simply never set the variable to the controller you want. Oh, and if that's the parent, don't forget to make the var `weak`, or you'll run into a retain cycle.

Comment: Check the link it will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegates or protocol. [click here](http://stephenradford.me/creating-a-delegate-in-swift/)

if you have to update views then you can use nsnotificationcenter [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191802/2511019)

Comment: You should add some code too, because links might break in future, or post it as a comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yoa can simply send action to your destination view controller to set the values like `UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction("setTempInCelsious", to: nil, from: nil, forEvent: nil)`

Hope this helps.