# show a custome view when notification receive in active application

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I need to show a universal custom view whenever i received a notification in a active app.
I have created a view , but i am not getting how to show that!
Can anyone help me out.[image]

Comment: check this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c .if any problem than tell me

Comment: Accept answer which helps you

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the notification in the `AppDelegate` methods (usually `application(_:​did​Receive​Remote​Notification:​fetch​Completion​Handler:​)`) and launch the view in the form it can be shown in any screen of your app.

You can read the docs for `UIApplicationDelegate` [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate), section **Responding to Notifications and Events**.

Answer (score 0):

You will be receiving the push notification in AppDelegate's application(_:​did​Receive​Remote​Notification:​fetch​Completion​Handler:​) from here you can handle.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))handler
{
 // 1. You can call your universal view from here

               OR

 // 2. You can post this local notification with information
 NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myObject forKey:@"info"];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showNotification"
                                                     object:nil
                                                   userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

For 2nd Option, you will need add observer and receiving method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) 
        name:@"showNotification"
        object:nil];

-(void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // call your view
}
```