# Function is not fired in dismiss completion block

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a view controller which is dismissed when a user logs in. In the dismiss function completion block I have fired a function which should reload the next view controller. Nothing happens, blank view controller. But if I close the application when I am already logged in, then reopen it, everything loads like it should.

So here is my login function:

```
func loginFunc() {

        if emailField.text != "" && passwordField.text != "" {

            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

                if user != nil {
                    // Sign In Successful
                    print("Sign In Sucessful")
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                        self.mainVC.starterMethod()
                    })
                } else {

                    if let myError = error?.localizedDescription {
                        print(myError)
                    } else {
                        print("Error")
                    }

                }

            })

        }

    }
```

And here is my `starterMethod()`:

```
func starterMethod() {

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        if userId != nil {
            print("You are logged in...")
        } else {
            present(LoginController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        setupPicks()
        setupViewsMed()
        fetchGames()
        setNavigationBar()
        setupCircles()

    }
```

`starterMethod()` is called in the `viewDidLoad`

I would really like to avoid `viewDidAppear()` if possible

Comment: Is your `completionBlock` @escaping? if it is, you have memory leak (it is bad, but it should work because self is persisted in memory and has access to `mainVC`. if it's not @escaping, you definitely will freeze the UI, and there won't be any memory leaks, BUT after dismiss completion handler, self no longer exists hence mainVC should not exist

Comment: You can even use Notification. delegate sounds fine as others said, but authenticating is more abstract than a hook between two VCs, after user successfully logged in, send a Notification, and add an observer in MainVC

Comment: @farzadshbfn How would implementing Notification and observer look like. Could you please help me a little more? :)

Comment: I don't have access to my computer at the moment, but this thread will give you the basic idea... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c

Comment: @farzadshbfn Great! Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Prior to iOS12 **dismiss** (and it's completion) is not called if there is no **presentingViewController**.
On iOS13+ **dismiss** doesn't work, but it's completion is called

Comment: Hi Vadim Zhuk, how did you find out this? Is it documented somewhere by Apple?

Comment: No, it's not documented by Apple - mb this is a bug, but this method(and its completion) should work only in case of modal presentation, at the same time the completion is called (on ios13+) even if the dismiss method doesn't work

Comment: I noticed that the completion also is not called when isBeingDismissed already was true on iOS 12 and older. On iOS 13 and newer isBeingDismissed is true during interactive dismissal (that can be aborted), so there it's better to rely on the completion.

Answer (score 3):

For that i think Delegate method is best suited for you. Because dismissed view controller want to notify to presenting view controller.

From Apple's documentation.

> When it comes time to dismiss a presented view controller, the
>   preferred approach is to let the presenting view controller dismiss
>   it. In other words, whenever possible, the same view controller that
>   presented the view controller should also take responsibility for
>   dismissing it. Although there are several techniques for notifying the
>   presenting view controller that its presented view controller should
>   be dismissed, the preferred technique is delegation.

Answer (score 2):

From your code below

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
     self.mainVC.starterMethod()
})
```

from the code i can assume that you have instance of mainVC **(self.mainVC)** created in current class which is being displayed.

After current view is dissmissed you might probably loosing reference of you mainVC and causing the issue.

**Solution :**

You can use delegate method or Notification to listen to the event in main vc.

You need to create this below protocol in your Current view controller
    @protocol LoginDoneProtocol {
        func loginAndDismissed()
    }
confirms to the protocol in your mainVC, like

```
Class mainVC : UIViewCOntroller , LoginDoneProtocol {
}
```

You can implement the delegate method in your mainVC, inside the delegate method call your method to reset the values

```
func loginAndDismissed(){
    starterMethod()
}
```

On the comppletionBlock of Dismissing your viewcontroller you can simply call

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

delegate.loginAndDismissed()

})
```

Note : You must assign delegate to current View Controller from your mainVC when your current View Controller is presented.

You will many tutorial on how to create delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the solution. I imagine it is the easiest approach and very reliable.

First of all I declared a constant:

```
let LOGGED_IN_NOTIFICATION = NSNotification.Name("LoggedInNotification")
```

Then in the `dismiss` method completion block I added:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: LOGGED_IN_NOTIFICATION, object: nil)
```

And finally added an observer in the `mainVC's viewDidLoad` method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: LOGGED_IN_NOTIFICATION, object: nil, queue: nil) {
            notification in

            print("Logged in")

            self.reset()

            self.starterMethod()

        }

    self.starterMethod()

}
```