# Navigate and pass the string to another VC embedded in a TabVC and NavigationVC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, nstabviewcontroller

I have the following Storyboard. [image: Pic]

I wish to pass a string say sURL to Classes VC. Classes VC is embedded in a Tab View Controller and a Navigation Controller. Your help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: you can use custom delegate or notificationcenter to communicate with viewcontroller

Comment: Can you show me an example please, how about directing to another view controller? is it something like this

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UITabBarController *tabView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileView"];
        [self presentViewController:tabView animated:YES completion:nil]; 

      but profile view is initial my TabView Controller, how do I direct to Classes VC?

Comment: Custom delegate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12660523/1142743. notificationcenter : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191802/1142743 or use UserDefaults to store the value that's the simplest way

Comment: I think i got it will post a solution later, Thanks Vinodh, I just need to name my storyboard.

Comment: okay you can post your own solution

Comment: Use the custom property or [segue](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+segue+pass+data&oq=ios+segue). DO NOT use the `NSNotificationCenter` or `NSUserDefaults` please!

Comment: Hi Itachi, the `prepareForSegue:` method to pass value only works between 2 controllers that pushes? 
Does it work with VC that is beyond not pushed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Store what ever string that you want to pass into NSDefaults and then at the other VC call the NSDefaults again.

```
//=== Strore into session and send over to Classes VC
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:sURLToClass forKey:@"txtURLFromSearch"];
[defaults synchronize];

//=== This is to call Classes VC
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tabView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileView"];
tabView.selectedIndex=0; //=== This is to choose which Tab, starts with 0,1,2,3,4
[self presentViewController:tabView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Don't use `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]`. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414005-synchronize?language=objc) _"this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."_